# Open react native application from email when i click on button instead of link(URL) from email

Tags: android, ios, react-native, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I had implemented **deep linking** in react-native android, universal links in react-native ios. It works fine when I click the link or URL from an email app or any messenger my react-native app opens.

**But there is a button instead of a link in the mail.
if I click the button my react native app does not open its redirecting to a webpage,
I want to open my app when I click on the button instead of the link or URL from the email app.**

*For example, if we click the **manage order** button in mail send by Flipkart from the email app in our mobile Flipkart app opens.*

Comment: Are you trying to open a native application installed on your phone? For Android, that would have to be an installed APK. Or are you trying to open an HTML link which will run in your browser?

Comment: I am trying to open react native app that was installed in my mobile already.

Answer (score 1):

It should open the app if the URL is already added to support in-app deep linking.
check if any intermediate redirections(ex:- short URLs are used) are happening before it reaches the end URL. You can check if it's a valid deep link URL by copying the button link in the email from the browser.

Answer (score -1):

You can use HTML to display a button in your email.